# Using history.push correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to use history.push to link to another page on my React app upon a button click but when I use history.push, it gives me the error `Unexpected use of 'history'.(no-restricted-globals)`

```
<ExampleComponent handleClick={history.push('/path/to/page')} text={'something'} />
```

Inside the ExampleComponent, I have a button with an onClick handler that calls the handleClick props

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.text}</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**update**

When you use ExampleComponent component there is a problem with the variable history. As this is globally reachable as windows.history. I think you call `history.push` the linter gives a warning if it is window.history or not.

Comment: It still gives me the same error when I add the arrow function in.

Comment: nevermind, i got it to work by removing the arrow function in ExampleComponent

Comment: Oh I just figured it out, I think. But I'm glad you found out also.